# fav button in CollectionViewCell - Swift

Tags: swift

I use the favorite button in CollectionView. I have defined different images according to the false or true status of this favorite button. I want to save these true and false states inside the application. For this, I firstly defined different images with values ​​of true or false. The moment I make it true or false, I save the data in the keychain to the selectedButtonNew key and put the selectedButtonNew key in the id of the newDAVID by making a get bool. In this way, I assign a different true false value to each id. But it doesn't work the way it is now. True, false values ​​are recorded incorrectly.

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    cell.callback = { [unowned self] flag in
        self.yeniDavID[indexPath.row] = flag
        self.keychain.set(flag, forKey: "selectedButtonNew")
    }

    cell.FavouritButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(favDavetiye(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.FavouritButton.accessibilityElements = [indexPath]
}

@objc func favDavetiye(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let index = sender.accessibilityElements?.first as! IndexPath

    let davID = yeniDavID[index.row]
    let buttondeger = keychain.getBool("selectedButtonNew")
    self.keychain.set(buttondeger!, forKey: "\(davID)")
}
```

**CELL**

```swift
class sonsuzCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var FavouritButton: UIButton!

    var callback : ((String) -> ())?
    var flag = Bool()

    @IBAction func FavouritButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if self.flag == true {
                let image1 = UIImage(named: "star-2favsiz") as UIImage?
                self.FavouritButton.setImage(image1, for: .normal)
                self.flag = false
                print(self.flag)
                //  self.webService(Action: "set_favourite_book", BookId: sender.tag)
                sender.isSelected = false
                self.callback?("true")
            } else {
                let image1 = UIImage(named: "star") as UIImage?
                self.FavouritButton.setImage(image1, for: .normal)
                self.flag = true
                sender.isSelected = true
                self.callback?("false")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't understand ... why you are saving in keychain ?

Comment: When I opened the application, I recorded that the button in that id is true or false and made it to come true or false in the same way. @jawadAli

Comment: use `userDefault` instead of keychain

Comment: Your using keychain to pass the bool value between methods, and your using keychain for just storing bool values which is not sensitive at all. non-sensitive data should use UserDefaults..